# Normal model and IEnumerable model in same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

Have a little problem, which I cannot solve by myself. I want to use same model in one view, but once with IEnumerable<> and second time without it.

My View:

```
@model IEnumerable<AMBIT_CMS_MVC.Areas.Admin.Models.Product>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>DYSKRET - FOLIE OKIENNE</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/Site.css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap.css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/buttons.js")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid okienne">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 menu">
                <a href="http://dyskret.pl/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="~/Images/logo.png" class="img-responsive fimg" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 lista">
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Produkt", new { ProductID = item.ProductID })</li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 details">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 footerProducts">
                Text...
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that foreach loop will work perfectly (I want to list all the products in this category), but when clicked I want to show also details of it on right, but I cannot because the model is IEnumerable<> and should be simple model (AMBIT_CMS_MVC.Areas.Admin.Models.Product). It's like I want to have Index and Details views in one. How can I achieve this?

Comment: All you view shows at the moment is links, so when you click on its, it will redirect, not show its details on the same page. If you do want to show the details of the clicked item on the same page, then you need ajax to call a method that returns a partial view (or json) and update the DOM. There is no need at all to have `Product` in addition to `IEnumerable<Product>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out the answer:

Changed my View to:

```
@model AMBIT_CMS_MVC.Models.ProductViewModel

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>DYSKRET - FOLIE OKIENNE</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/Site.css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap.css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/buttons.js")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid okienne">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 menu">
                <a href="http://dyskret.pl/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="~/Images/logo.png" class="img-responsive fimg" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 lista">
                @Html.Partial("_Lista", Model.Products)
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 details">
                @Html.Partial("_Produkt", Model.ProductDetails)
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 footerProducts">
                Text...
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

_Lista partial:

```
@model IEnumerable<AMBIT_CMS_MVC.Areas.Admin.Models.Product>

<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Produkt", new { ProductID = item.ProductID })</li>
    }
</ul>
```

_Produkt partial:

```
@model AMBIT_CMS_MVC.Areas.Admin.Models.Product

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Description)
```

Then added a class into my models - ProductViewModel(added into usings my areas models to work with them, because this model is outside areas):

```
using AMBIT_CMS_MVC.Areas.Admin.Models;
namespace AMBIT_CMS_MVC.Models
{
    public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public Product ProductDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And finally changed my controller to:

```
public ActionResult Produkt(int? ProductID)
        {
            string domain = Request.Url.Host;
            int clientid = (from a in db.Client where a.Domain == domain select a.ID).First();

            int categoryID = db.Category.Where(b => b.ClientID == clientid && b.Name == "Okienne").Select(b => b.ID).First();

            var ProductViewModel = new ProductViewModel();
            ProductViewModel.Products = db.Product.Where(c => c.ClientID == clientid && c.CategoryID == categoryID).ToList();
            ProductViewModel.ProductDetails = db.Product.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ClientID == clientid && c.CategoryID == categoryID && c.ProductID == ProductID);

            return View(ProductViewModel);
```

So here it is how I made it. Hope it will help the future generation of developers occurring the same errors and facing same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Tuple` method normal model and `IEnumerble` model

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ProjectX.Models;

namespace ProjectX.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Student
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ProjectX.DAL.ProjectContext db = new ProjectX.DAL.ProjectContext();
            // DAL is Data Access Layer Folder's name

            return View(Tuple.Create<Student, IEnumerable<Student>>(new Student(), db.Student.ToList()));
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Tuple<ProjectX.Models.Student,IEnumerable<ProjectX.Models.Student>>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_StudentLayout.cshtml";
}

<table>
    <thead>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item1.student_name)
        <th />
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item1.student_surname)
        <th />
    <thead />
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Item2)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.student_name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.student_surname)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    <tbody />
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to achieve this.

1. Use a view model. By utilizing a view model, you can have each as a separate property:

   ```
   public class ProductViewModel
   {
       public IEnumerable<Product> AllProducts { get; set; }
       public Product ActiveProduct { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Then, you can iterate using `Model.AllProducts` and display the single product the user clicked via `Model.ActiveProduct`.
2. Use a partial and select a product from the list to pass to it. First off, this will require your model to be `List<Product>` instead of `IEnumerable<Product>`. You can't both iterate over and query an enumerable. With that change, though, you can iterate over all the products as you current are, and then just render the clicked product via:

   ```
   @Html.Partial("_Product", Model.SingleOrDefault(m => m.ProductID == Request["ProductID"]))
   ```

   Technically, you don't even have to use a partial here. You could just set the result of that query to a variable in Razor and then utilize that to render the HTML directly in the same view.
3. Use a child action. With a child action, you get a totally separate context to work with, which means you can utilize a different model for the view as well. Just add something like the following to your controller:

   ```
   [ChildActionOnly]
   public ActionResult DisplayProduct(int productID)
   {
       var product = // retrieve product by id;
       return PartialView("_Product", product);
   }
   ```

   Then, in your view:

   ```
   @Html.Action("DisplayProduct", new { productID = Request["productID"] })
   ```

Comment: In all of above I get such an error:
System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Product_A7BFD8CBC1EFF80F0680459A04247BF1252FBF745FD7875CD7B2FE3DE3A233C2', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[AMBIT_CMS_MVC.Areas.Admin.Models.Product]'.
On second option it only changes IEnumerable to List.

Comment: For option 1, you would need to both pass an instance of your view model and change the view's model declaration to represent that. For option 2 and 3, you need to pass an actual list of products. Right now, based on the error, you're only sending a single model instance to the view.