# PartialView with Index/Create pages?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

Just wondering if anyone can clear up the correct theory or method of having a partial view between my Index and Create pages. Essentially what I am trying to achieve is an Index page that lets me add new entries (Create).

Standard .net core 5 project scaffolded from a DB table, the main issues seems to be that the Index uses and IEnumerable and the Create page uses just the Model. I have tried both ways Index to Create / Create to Index to implement a partial view, when working with two Model pages like Create and Edit the partial view implements easily as expected.

There are many ways in asp.net older versions it seems but this works for like models

`@Html.Partial("_CreatePartial")`

Is a partial view what I am looking for? Or is there a better way to do things? Just hard to figure out what options I even have as far as googling stuff. I see a lot of asp.net examples don't have issues like this or don't include lists or models.

I would think this is a somewhat basic and common request, just a pointer in the right direction and terms to research would be appreciated.

**Edit**

My Index.cshtml starts with
`@model IEnumerable<TNA.Models.Tna>`

My Create/Edit/Delete starts with
`@model TNA.Models.Tna`

**Error message is this**
`` InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TNA.Models.Tna]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'TNA.Models.Tna'. ``

So I am trying to insert a PartialView from a model into a page that is based on an Enumerable list. Can't see any hints online, I have tried other deprecated methods that present other challenges revolving around the same thing.

Index

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeId)
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>

**@Html.Partial("_CreatePartial")**
```

Create

```
@model TNA_BWEL.Models.TnaBwel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>TnaBwel</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Date" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Date" type="date" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Date" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Controller

```
namespace TNA.Controllers
{
    public class TnasController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public TnasController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Tnas
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Tnas.ToListAsync());
        }

        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Date")] Tna tna)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(tna);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(tna);
        }
```

Partial views are near identical to standard views, not much to see since it is a scaffolded new project, never done this before in a .net project and was trying to get the unknowns out of the way.

Comment: I think you're going to have to share some code that highlights your problem. "the main issues seems to be that the Index uses and IEnumerable and the Create page uses just the Model." This doesn't make a ton of sense without context.

Comment: Thanks @JoelChristophel added some more context to help make things more clear

Comment: Have you tried passing `null` as the model? `@Html.Partial("_CreatePartial", null)`

Comment: Same issues, stumbled upon some similar questions just not sure how to interpret it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209410/normal-model-and-ienumerable-model-in-same-view

Anyone have any other advice where to start, I think using the scaffolded pages may not be as logical as I could find and learn myself from scratch?